# Swift 2.0 - CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null)

Tags: ios, swift, api, core-data, swift2

I have a `DB.swift` file in order to use Core Data. In my `persistentStoreCoordinator`, in the line of `abort()`, I am receiving the error that I wrote below.

This is how my code looks:

```
    lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {

    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("MyAppData", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
}()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {

    var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("coredata.sqlite")
    var error: NSError? = nil
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    do {
        try coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
    } catch {
        coordinator = nil

        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
        let wrapperError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)

        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

        NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(wrapperError.userInfo)")
        abort() // ~ Here I am receiving error ~
    }

    return coordinator
}()
```

> `2015-11-13 17:14:09.432 MyTestApp[17121:1577592] CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null) URL:file:///Users/sentiasa/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3E42AB50-BBB1-4190-93E1-2EFF77FCA7CB/data/Containers/Data/Application/F4E05308-852A-42E0-AB5A-8712CD6FD508/Documents/coredata.sqlite options:(null) ... returned error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134100 "(null)" UserInfo={metadata={
>       NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 640;
>       NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
>           Users = <3d1a75c4 8f710e63 26eb5f88 c4fe6477 b2af77a8 6f9d5600 6abaf2bc 2c6ba1da>;
>       };
>       NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
>       NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
>           ""
>       );
>       NSStoreType = SQLite;
>       NSStoreUUID = "A979CF18-B316-4989-B118-A1CE44C0AAE8";
>       "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
>   }, reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store} with userInfo dictionary {
>       metadata =     {
>           NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 640;
>           NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
>               Users = <3d1a75c4 8f710e63 26eb5f88 c4fe6477 b2af77a8 6f9d5600 6abaf2bc 2c6ba1da>;
>           };
>           NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
>           NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
>               ""
>           );
>           NSStoreType = SQLite;
>           NSStoreUUID = "A979CF18-B316-4989-B118-A1CE44C0AAE8";
>           "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
>       };
>       reason = "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store";
>   }
>   2015-11-13 17:14:09.435 MyTestApp[17121:1577592] Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134100 "(null)" UserInfo={metadata={
>       NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 640;
>       NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
>           Users = <3d1a75c4 8f710e63 26eb5f88 c4fe6477 b2af77a8 6f9d5600 6abaf2bc 2c6ba1da>;
>       };
>       NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
>       NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
>           ""
>       );
>       NSStoreType = SQLite;
>       NSStoreUUID = "A979CF18-B316-4989-B118-A1CE44C0AAE8";
>       "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
>   }, reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store}, [NSLocalizedDescription: Failed to initialize the application's saved data, NSLocalizedFailureReason: There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data., NSUnderlyingError: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134100 "(null)" UserInfo={metadata={
>       NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 640;
>       NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
>           Users = <3d1a75c4 8f710e63 26eb5f88 c4fe6477 b2af77a8 6f9d5600 6abaf2bc 2c6ba1da>;
>       };
>       NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
>       NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
>           ""
>       );
>       NSStoreType = SQLite;
>       NSStoreUUID = "A979CF18-B316-4989-B118-A1CE44C0AAE8";
>       "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
>   }, reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store}]
>   (lldb)

Comment: The error message states the reason quite plainly: "reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store" so your model has changed since creating the original store.  You should either remove the store and replace it with a new one (if just in development), or you should employ a migration strategy.

Comment: Reseting Simulator solved the problem, cheers!